# Is there a way for Spark to read AWS S3 files without using Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark

Stand-alone programs can read / write AWS S3 files without Hadoop by using AWS client jar files.  Spark programs can read / write files without Hadoop.  Yet Spark require programs that read / write AWS S3 files to use Hadoop.  And even so, there are run-time errors with Spark 1.4 and Hadoop 2.6 & 2.7 about missing Hadoop's class for S3 even though Hadoop directory is set.

1. Is there a way for Spark programs to read / write S3 files without using Hadoop by using AWS client jar files ?
2. If not, how do I resolve the Spark's issue with missing Hadoop's class for S3 at run-time ?

Comment: did you find a way of reading / writing from S3 without using Hadoop?

Answer (score 4):

Spark uses Hadoop classes to read S3 but it doesn't require Hadoop installation (we're using the prebuilt for Hadoop 2.4 version). Just make sure you use `s3n://` prefixes

Comment: Thanks, Arnon, for the clarification.  However, it would be even better that Spark uses AWS S3 client jar instead of Hadoop client jar file, so that 

1. generic Spark could be used instead of relying variation of Spark built just for specific version of Hadoop.
   For instance, the above run-time issue comes up with Spark 1.4 and Hadoop 2.7.1
   
2. There would be less external dependencies: AWS S3 jar can be just bundled for compile and run vs having to rebuild Spark for specific version of Hadoop.

For S3 files access from Spark, is there a way to use AWS S3 client jar instead?

Comment: I agree it would be better - since this way there are a lot of problems with Spark assuming S3 is a regular filesystem.  I saw https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pjrt/f1cad93b154ac8958e65/raw/7b0b764408f145f51477dc05ef1a99e8448bce6d/S3Puller.scala where they've offered bringing the file(s) using the AWS client and then parallelizing the result but I haven't tried it myself

Comment: Here's the link to the article http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219